# How to download string from another page inside the project

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have my `ashx` handler, which responses a string.

```
context.Response.Write("test");
```

How can I get this string in another web form?

I have tried:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
        html2 = client.DownloadString("~/handles/myhandler.ashx");
```

but this does not seem to work with relative urls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`WebClient` will make an HTTP request. So it needs to know the entire URL. It is just like you're entering the URL into your browser.

From the docs:

> If the BaseAddress property is not an empty string ("") and address
>   does not contain an absolute URI, address must be a relative URI that
>   is combined with BaseAddress to form the absolute URI of the requested
>   data. If the QueryString property is not an empty string, it is
>   appended to address.

Ref:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xz398a3f.aspx

Comment: I don't know the entire URL. And, I don't have to use `WebClient`. Is there any other way of achieving this?

Comment: Can't you prefix your relative URL with your domain name on which your application resides? You can perhaps move that into the configuration and get it from there? so that you wont have to change the code

Comment: It's not only the URL, I have the handler under login, and all I'd get as response is the login page.